# How to parse a JSON object from ajax call in Java Script

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

I am making an Ajax call in my JSP which is recieving a JSON response.

Running `alert('Ajax Response ' + respArr);` gives the following screen:

[image: Screenshot of Alert message]

The Java server-side code:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        String fromDate = request.getParameter("drFrom");
        String toDate = request.getParameter("drTo");
        JSONArray jsonArray = chartData.getCCSBJson(fromDate, toDate);
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        res.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());
    }
```

The JavaScript:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    if(xmlhttp.responseText != null) {
        var respArr = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var jsonData = eval("(" + respArr + ")");
        alert('JSON Chart ' + jsonData); // The line from above
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
        alert('JSON Parse' + obj);
```

The JSON that is being returned:

```
[
  {
    "chart":{
      "caption":"",
      "exportDataFormattedVal":"1",
      "numberPrefix":"",
      "showexportdatamenuitem":"1",
      "xAxisName":"Bureau usage",
      "yAxisName":"count"
    },
    "data":[
      {
        "label":"SB AutoDecison",
        "value":"0"
      },
      {
        "label":"CC AutoDecison",
        "value":"0"
      },
      {
        "label":"CC Judgemental",
        "value":"0"
      },
      {
        "label":"SB Judgemental",
        "value":"0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The alerts result:

```
alert('JSON Chart ' + jsonData) // JSON Chart[object Object]
alert('JSON Parse ' + obj);     // JSON parse[object Object]
```

What I want is to parse the object and generate an Excel sheet out of the content.

When I try to loop:

```
var jqueryData = jQuery.parseJSON(respArr);
var obj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
for (var i in obj) {
    alert('For loop string' + obj[i]);
}
```

It throws some 7 or 8 alerts with JavaScript code

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    alert(i + ' of respArr ' + respArr[i]);
}
```

Gives letter after letter of the JSON: `[`, `{`, `"`, `c`, `h`, and so on for each iteration of the loop.

Can I not just traverse the JSON like `respArr[0].data` or `respArr[0].chart`?

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: I removed the jQuery tag.. but I now see the `jqueryData` variable.. even though there isn't actually any jQuery in what you've shown us, and `jqueryData` isn't defined anywhere.. so if I was wrong to remove the jQuery tag, please add it back.

Comment: try to use console.log in place of alert, it will help to debug fast

Comment: Don't use alert, use console.log, it'll show the object.

Comment: Help me parsing the Json object...  respArr[0].chart says undefined..I just tried multiple ways of parsing JSon.. Not issue with the jQuery..

Comment: alert('zero of resp Arr '+respArr[0].data); says undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

First, your Java servlet is not really returning a "string". When you write `jsonArray.toString()`, yes, you are turning the array into a string, but that is solely for the purpose of writing it across the network. HTTP is a text protocol. So, what the `doGet` method is actually returning, in a sense, is a HTTP response (it just happens to be as text, it could very well be binary).

With that, when a client (in this case, your JavaScript via `XMLHttpRequest`) makes a `GET` request to your server (your servlet), it is getting back the JSON response (yes, as text). Your `xmlhttp.responseText` variable in this case *should* contain the JSON you've shown in the question.

Calling one of:

- `JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText)`
- `jQuery.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText)`
- `$.parseJSON(xmlhttp.responseText)`

Should all return you the same object. With this object you can access its properties the way you want to. The following *should* work:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
    if (xmlhttp.responseText != null) {
        var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
        var arr = JSON.parse(json);
        var data = arr[0].data;       // This is what you want to do?
        var chart = arr[0].chart;     // This is what you want to do?
        // try running alert(chart.xAxisName);
        // and so on
```

**Side note**: When you run `alert(obj);` where `obj` is a object, you are seeing `[object Object]` because that is how JavaScript represents objects as strings. If you want to see the internals of a JavaScript object, as others have pointed out, you are better off using `console.log(obj)`. (Also, upgrade or switch to a better browser. You will have access to better debugging tools.)

Answer (score 1):

Your json  response has this structure:

```
[
   {
      "chart":{
         "caption":"",
         "exportDataFormattedVal":"1",
         "numberPrefix":"",
         "showexportdatamenuitem":"1",
         "xAxisName":"Bureau usage",
         "yAxisName":"count"
      },
      "data":[
         {
            "label":"SB AutoDecison",
            "value":"0"
         },
         {
            "label":"CC AutoDecison",
            "value":"0"
         },
         {
            "label":"CC Judgemental",
            "value":"0"
         },
         {
            "label":"SB Judgemental",
            "value":"0"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Access the the 1st element of the outermost object like `response[0]`.
And then the chart object within it like `response[0].chart` and so on.
http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ will help format the JSON and make it readable.

Comment: You mean var respArr = xmlhttp.responseText;  alert(respArr[0]);  ------------> gives [          alert(response[0].chart);  -----------> gives undefined...

Answer (score 1):

Check out this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/38G6a/1/)**

You can access the properties of your object directly.

```
$(function () {

    var q = [{
        "chart": {
            "caption": "",
                "exportDataFormattedVal": "1",
                "numberPrefix": "",
                "showexportdatamenuitem": "1",
                "xAxisName": "Bureau usage",
                "yAxisName": "count"
        },
            "data": [{
            "label": "SB AutoDecison",
                "value": "0"
        }, {
            "label": "CC AutoDecison",
                "value": "0"
        }, {
            "label": "CC Judgemental",
                "value": "0"
        }, {
            "label": "SB Judgemental",
                "value": "0"
        }]
    }];

    console.log(q);
    console.log(q[0].data);
    q[0].data.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.label);
        console.log(item.value);
    });

});
```

Comment: Iam testing in IE 9 ... is Fire Bug available for in IE9

Comment: Press `F12`. There's a console there (a really poor one, though)

Comment: Afterreplacing console.log(q[0].data);  with  alert('zero of resp Arr '+respArr[0].data); says undefined....

Comment: @Technomation have you changed the variable's name?

Comment: No I didnt..Pls chck the screen i have attached of   alert('Ajax Response '+respArr);     alert('zero of resp Arr '+respArr[0].data); says undefined

Comment: for(i=0;i<5; i++){alert(i+' of resp Arr '+respArr[i]);}  gives letter after letter of the Json.. like   [  {  "  c  h  .......