# How to send Json to JSP from servlet , with out converting it to a String

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json, jsp

I have an Ajax call in my JSP which returns a JSON object in the form of Java string.

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {
        String fromDate = request.getParameter("drFrom");
        String toDate = request.getParameter("drTo");
        JSONArray jsonArray = chartData.getCCSBJson(fromDate, toDate);
        res.setContentType("application/json");
        res.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());
```

Can I send the JSON to JSP without using  `jsonArray.toString()` inside `res.getWriter().write(jsonArray.toString());`, because I am not able to parse the JSON in JSP after sending it as a string.

This is related to the post: [How to parse a JSON object from ajax call in Java Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022341/how-to-parse-a-json-object-from-ajax-call-in-java-script)

Comment: There should be no problem when converting a `JSONXxx` object to String because that's the real JSON format. The problem is in your `JSONArray`. Post the code for `chartData.getCCSBJson(fromDate, toDate)`. Or maybe the problem is in JSP side. Post how you're parsing the String in your client.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse a JSON object from ajax call in Java Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24022341/how-to-parse-a-json-object-from-ajax-call-in-java-script)

Answer (score 3):

Simply parse the JSON string into Java object in Servlet itself and pass the Java Object to the JSP instead of plain String.

#### Steps to follow:

- Simply create a Java POJO class that is replica of JSON string
- Convert the JSON string into POJO class object in the Servlet itself
- Set the object in HTTP request as an attribute
- Get the object back from HTTP request in JSP

**Note:** Java POJO class must be `Serializable`.

Try with [JavaScript - JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method that parses a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing in JavaScript.